# How to subset a data after intersecting in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, subset

I have 3 sets of data taken from URL and 1 user input CSV file. All 4 datasets are yearly, and the time period available is different. I want all 4 data for the same period for my further calculation. I did some checking and found I could intersect the 4 data (GTA, SST, DMI, and AMP) and subset using the intersected result. This is how did it in r.

```
n <- intersect(intersect(intersect(AMP$Year,SST$Year), GTA$Year),DMI$Year)
AMP1 <- subset(AMP, Year %in% intersect(AMP$Year,n))
```

I want this in my shiny App. This is a portion of my shiny App that I created to subset my data. I worked out the intersect part. Now I need help with how to subset my data using my intersected column?

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)

a <- fread('https://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/data/indices/sstoi.indices',header = TRUE)
b <- as.matrix(a[,c(1,2,9)])
df <- data.frame( Year = b[,1],month = b[,2], value = b[,3])
SS <- df %>% filter(!between(month, 4, 10)) %>%
  arrange(Year, month) %>%
  filter(!(Year == min(Year) & month %in% 1:3 | 
             Year == max(Year) & month %in% 11:12)) %>%
  group_by(grp = cumsum(month == 11)) %>%
  summarise(Year = last(Year),
            value = mean(value)) %>%
  select(-grp)

SST <- as.matrix(SS) 

d <- fread('https://www.metoffice.gov.uk/hadobs/hadcrut4/data/current/time_series/HadCRUT.4.6.0.0.annual_ns_avg.txt',
           header = FALSE)

GTA <- as.matrix(d[,1:2])

dat <- fread('https://psl.noaa.gov/gcos_wgsp/Timeseries/Data/dmi.had.long.data',header = FALSE,fill = TRUE)
e <- dat[,c(1,7:12)][complete.cases(dat[,c(1,7:12)]),]
f <- matrix(as.numeric(unlist(e)),nrow=nrow(e))
g <- replace(f, f== -9999.000, NA)
h <- g[complete.cases(g),]
me = rowMeans(h[,2:7],na.rm = T)

DMI <- as.matrix(data.frame(Year = h[,1],value = me)) 


ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file", "Choose observation precipitation CSV File", accept = ".csv"),
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput('ID')
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  inputdata <- reactive({
    infile = input$file
    if(is.null(infile))
      return(NULL)
    df <- read.csv(infile$datapath,header=input$header)
    return(df)
  })
  output$ID <- renderTable({
    req(inputdata())
    AMP <- as.matrix(inputdata())
    n <- intersect(intersect(intersect(AMP[,1],SST[,1]), GTA[,1]),DMI[,1])
  return(n)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The AMP data is user input, but it can be taken as below.

```
set.seed(123)
df1 <- data.frame(year = rep(1971:2013),value = rnorm(43))
```

If a there better way to do this, I am all ears. I didn't find a lot on comparing more than 2 data frames in r.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try this -

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)

a <- fread('https://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/data/indices/sstoi.indices',header = TRUE)
b <- as.matrix(a[,c(1,2,9)])
df <- data.frame( Year = b[,1],month = b[,2], value = b[,3])
SS <- df %>% filter(!between(month, 4, 10)) %>%
  arrange(Year, month) %>%
  filter(!(Year == min(Year) & month %in% 1:3 | 
             Year == max(Year) & month %in% 11:12)) %>%
  group_by(grp = cumsum(month == 11)) %>%
  summarise(Year = last(Year),
            value = mean(value)) %>%
  select(-grp)

SST <- as.matrix(SS) 

d <- fread('https://www.metoffice.gov.uk/hadobs/hadcrut4/data/current/time_series/HadCRUT.4.6.0.0.annual_ns_avg.txt',
           header = FALSE)

GTA <- as.matrix(d[,1:2])

dat <- fread('https://psl.noaa.gov/gcos_wgsp/Timeseries/Data/dmi.had.long.data',header = FALSE,fill = TRUE)
e <- dat[,c(1,7:12)][complete.cases(dat[,c(1,7:12)]),]
f <- matrix(as.numeric(unlist(e)),nrow=nrow(e))
g <- replace(f, f== -9999.000, NA)
h <- g[complete.cases(g),]
me = rowMeans(h[,2:7],na.rm = T)

DMI <- as.matrix(data.frame(Year = h[,1],value = me)) 


ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file", "Choose observation precipitation CSV File", accept = ".csv"),
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput('ID')
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  inputdata <- reactive({
    infile = input$file
    if(is.null(infile))
      return(NULL)
    df <- read.csv(infile$datapath,header=input$header)
    df
  })
  output$ID <- renderTable({
    req(inputdata())
    AMP <- as.matrix(inputdata())
    n <- intersect(intersect(intersect(AMP[,1],SST[,1]), GTA[,1]),DMI[,1])
    AMP1 <- AMP[AMP[, 1] %in% n, ]
    AMP1
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```